# get Value of selected item in FlatList react native

Tags: reactjs, render, native, flatlist

I want to put the `item.cin` of the selected item  in data.

please help I didn't find a solution anywhere.

here is the code :

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      
      <View key={item.id} style={styles.rec}>
        <Text style={styles.recText}>{item.date}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.recText}>{item.nom}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.recText}>-{item.description}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.recDelete }>
          <Icon name="eye"
            size={24}
            color='white'
            onPress={onShowPopup}/>
            <AfficheRec 
            title="Réclamation"
            ref={(target)=>popupRef=target}
            onTouchOutside={onClosePopup}
            data={item}
           />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    )
  }
```

Comment: which data you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

you can define `state` for get selected parameter , like that ,

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      
      <View key={item.id} style={styles.rec}>
        <Text style={styles.recText}>{item.date}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.recText}>{item.nom}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.recText}>-{item.description}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.recDelete }>
          <Icon name="eye"
            size={24}
            color='white'
            onPress={
             onShowPopup
             this.setstate({mitem:item.cin})}/>
            <AfficheRec 
            title="Réclamation"
            ref={(target)=>popupRef=target}
            onTouchOutside={onClosePopup}
            data={item}
           />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    )
  }
```